# C# Xamarin Forms - CrossGeolocator.PositionChanged not being called

Tags: c#, xamarin, geolocation, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms to create an application that tracks your location. On my page `WhosOnFarm.xaml.cs` I have a function which detects when your location changes, which is using the `Plugins.Geolocator` class.

This piece of code is in the constructor of my page, which is called `WhosOnFarm()`, yet it is never called despite my attempts of manually changing the location information in my Android emulator, or walking around with my physical device with the app running on the `WhosOnFarm.xaml.cs` page.

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

locator.PositionChanged += (sender, e) => {
    try
    {
        DisplayAlert("Success", "Your position has changed!", "OK");
        var position = e.Position;
        longitudeLabel.Text = "Longitude: " + position.Longitude.ToString() + " Latitude: " + position.Latitude.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
                longitudeLabel.Text = "================= Trip Log encountered error - ========================== " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
};
```

Why is this code never executed?

Answer (score 1):

**Checking permissions**

Before tracking begine you must check to ensure that you have location permissions on all platforms. I recommend using the Permissions Plugin to ensure that you have permission.

**Start Tracking**

```
/// <summary>
/// Start listening for changes
/// </summary>
/// <param name="minimumTime">Time</param>
/// <param name="minimumDistance">Distance</param>
/// <param name="includeHeading">Include heading or not</param>
/// <param name="listenerSettings">Optional settings (iOS only)</param>
Task<bool> StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan minimumTime, double minimumDistance, bool includeHeading = false, ListenerSettings listenerSettings = null)
```

**UWP Note:** How the Geolocator works you must either set the minTime or the minDistance. Setting both means that minDistance will take precedence between the two. You can read more on the Windows blog.

```
async Task StartListening()
{
    if(CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
        return;

    ///This logic will run on the background automatically on iOS, however for Android and UWP you must put logic in background services. Else if your app is killed the location updates will be killed.
    await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
                {
                    ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
                    AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                    DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                    DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
                    DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
                    PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
                });

    CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += Current_PositionChanged;
}

private void Current_PositionChanged(object sender, Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.PositionEventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        var test = e.Position;
        listenLabel.Text = "Full: Lat: " + test.Latitude.ToString() + " Long: " + test.Longitude.ToString();
        listenLabel.Text += "\n" + $"Time: {test.Timestamp.ToString()}";
        listenLabel.Text += "\n" + $"Heading: {test.Heading.ToString()}";
        listenLabel.Text += "\n" + $"Speed: {test.Speed.ToString()}";
        listenLabel.Text += "\n" + $"Accuracy: {test.Accuracy.ToString()}";
        listenLabel.Text += "\n" + $"Altitude: {test.Altitude.ToString()}";
        listenLabel.Text += "\n" + $"AltitudeAccuracy: {test.AltitudeAccuracy.ToString()}";
    });
}
```

For more info use following link

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin